# How to schedule a python script to run at scheduled intervals in aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Current scenario**: We are processing 40M records using some java code and uploading them as csv files to s3 bucket.

**Future**: We want to move this code to AWS, for this we want to have a python script to process the records and load them as csv files in the aws-s3 bucket.
Can you suggest best way , which can trigger the script and process the data?
We want to avoid using EC2 and hosting python script in the server. we want to make it as a serverless service.

My approach:
I thought of doing this with AWS-Glue, using trigger (automatic/time based) to start the Job and will put my code in the script inside the job.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use AWS Fargate for that, it can be integrated with Lambda
>   considering maximum execution time of Lambda is 15 minutes, so you
>   should use Fargate

more details
https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-application-for-long-running-process-fargate-lambda/

Also you can use [AWS Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) to schedule it

Look solution always exists. But there is a good practice and bad practice.

> If I tell you, you can do that with just AWS lambda and AWS EventRule,
>   and SQS how would that sound. Interesting?

So in short you can do that. Track time consumed in lambda, when it reaches to 14 mins, send a message to SQS indicating your processed row number, upload processed file to s3, and quit. Use that SQS to trigger lambda again with some message retention as 30 seconds to invoke same lambda again and start from that row number. Once all processing completed you would have multiple processed files in S3, use another lambda and SQS to consolidate them into one. 
This isn't a bad practice but less good in my opinion, Happy?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Asfar, So do you want me to put my code in container as a package using fargate and integrate with lamda function or we can directly use AWS event rule to schedule fargate packaged code?

Comment: Its your choice but ideally Fargate can be invoked directly from Event Rule, so why use lambda (that would be extra)

Comment: can we do this with lamda step functions? or any other itntead of creating containers?

Comment: Edited answer, see

Comment: Thanks for the detail... So in short.. it is good to go with fargate :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Cloudwatch Event rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) to invoke on a regular schedule that you define and have your lambda function as it's target. here is a [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) in AWS Docs on how to do it.

Comment: my python code has to fetch 40+ million records of data and scrub it and upload it to s3 bucket as csv files , So will lamda function directly handles that volume?

Comment: your question was about triggering the script on a schedule. For handling such volume, i don't think Lambda will do it with its 15 minutes execution time limit.
How much time does it take for your script to process the records using a server ?

Comment: Does your java code get deployed to a lambda? If it does then you can write a python script that invokes this lambda at regular intervals using CloudWatch Event Rule. Your python script can keep invoking the lambda to cache the data. I am doing the same thing in my project. I have done a calculation for delta changes i.e., if my total records to be cached are 100k and 10k records have got cached in the 15 minutes time for which the lambda stays up, then I calculate the difference (total - cached) and the next time my python script triggers the lambda, it will cache the difference only.

Comment: @WalidK, Currently our java code is using mule servers and java streams concept to process the records and prepare the output file as csv and upload to aws s3 buckets. Now we want to migrate this processing to aws

Comment: @nrai, my current code is not in aws. It is just using aws s3 bucket to store the output csv files.